# What's the bar above x called in the sample mean?

Tags: mean, sample

What's the bar above x called in the sample mean? Is it a diacritic mark?

Comment: Some useful typographical information--but not dispositive, unfortunately--appears at http://en.vionto.com/show/me/Overline.  This source explicitly equates the term "overline" with the $\TeX$ "\bar" construct, which produces $\bar{x}$. However, in Unicode, multiple successive overlines connect up whereas multiple "macrons" remain separate, suggesting that the right way to create an *overline* for statistical typesetting is to use a Unicode *macron,* even though most sources would *call* it an overline!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's called a [vinculum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_%28symbol%29). On the other hand, MathWorld seems to think it's a [macron](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Macron.html). The distinction seems to be that a macron goes on top of single character, whereas a vinculum spans more than one. MathWorld seems to use [bar and macron interchangeably](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bar.html) and they cite Bringhurst, R. *The Elements of Typographic Style*, 2nd ed. Point Roberts, WA: Hartley and Marks, 1997, p. 271.

I would side with MathWorld, but you may get a better answer over at [the math site](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Wikipedia makes an interesting and (I think) useful distinction: a *macron* is intended to lengthen a vowel. As such, it has an inherent lexical and phonological meaning. An *overline* simply refers to the typographic mark. Clearly the former is not applicable to statistical usage, whereas the latter is.  Similarly, the *vinculum* has the specific purpose of uniting symbols. (I learned algebra long enough ago that the textbook included a vinculum along with parentheses and brackets as a way of grouping terms in algebraic expressions.) That, too, conflicts with statistical usage.

Comment: Vinculum means bond or chain in Latin, so it makes a lot of sense that it signifies the unity of a group. Bringhurst's 3rd edition does not mention the sample mean, only marking long vowels. I guess that leaves overbar/overline.

Answer (score -2):

"The overline is also used to indicate a sample mean"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline

While a macron is a Greek diacritic over a single symbol while "a line over a collection of symbols is a vinculum."
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron

Comment: Wikipedia thinks it's an [overline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline), not a macron.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. The page you link to mentions that the macron is *similar* to the **[overline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline)**, but these are not the same.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline
"Specifically, a line drawn over one symbol is a macron, and a line over a collection of symbols is a vinculum."

Comment: *An overline*
‾, unicode:203e HTML:&oline;
*is not a macron*
¯, unicode:0175, HTML:&macr;